# IllegalArgumentException (Illegal Base64 character) while decoding a Base64 image

Tags: java, javafx, base64

I'm using Java's Base64 decoder to decode an image and show it in an `ImageView`.

The exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a
```

Here's the code that gives this exception:

```
public class ThemeManager {
    private static final String MOON_ICON_BASE64 = "data:image/png;base64,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";
    private static final byte[] MOON_ICON_BYTEARRAY = Base64.getDecoder().decode(MOON_ICON_BASE64);
    public static final Image moonIcon = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(MOON_ICON_BYTEARRAY), 50, 50, true, true);
    
    // other code that doesn't matter for this issue
}
```

The `moonIcon` is used in another class, shown below:

```
public class LoginViewController {
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;
    
    public ControllerLoginView () {

    }
    
    public void initialize () {
        imageView.setImage(ThemeManager.moonIcon);
        // other code that doesn't matter for this issue
    }
}
```

How do I avoid getting that exception (without using a `File` object to load the icon)?

Edit: forgot to mention that I copy/pasted the Base64 string in an online decoder and it successfully decoded the image I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `data:image/png;base64,` part with `MOON_ICON_BASE64.split(",")[1]`

```
public class ThemeManager {
     private static final String MOON_ICON_BASE64 = "data:image/png;base64,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";
     private static final byte[] MOON_ICON_BYTEARRAY = Base64.getDecoder().decode(MOON_ICON_BASE64.split(",")[1]);
     public static final Image moonIcon = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(MOON_ICON_BYTEARRAY), 50, 50, true, true);

}
```